# bison and grammar: replaying the parse stack

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, bison

I have not messed with building languages or parsers in a formal way since grad school and have forgotten most of what I knew back then.  I now have a project that might benefit from such a thing but I'm not sure how to approach the following situation.

Let's say that in the language I want to parse there is a token that means "generate a random floating point number" in an expression.

```
exp: NUMBER
        {$$ = $1;}
    | NUMBER PLUS exp
        {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    | R PLUS exp
        {$$ = random() + $3;}
    ;
```

I also want a "list" generating operator that will reevaluate an "exp" some number of times.  Maybe like:

```
listExp: NUMBER COLON exp
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < $1; i++) {
            print $3;
        }
    }
    ;
```

The problem I see is that "exp" will have already been reduced by the time the loop starts.  If I have the input

```
2 : R + 2
```

then I think the random number will be generated as the "exp" is parsed and 2 added to it -- lets say the result is 2.0055.  Then in the list expression I think 2.0055 would be printed out twice.

Is there a way to mark the "exp" before evaluation and then parse it as many times as the list loop count requires?  The idea being to get a different random number in each evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to build an AST and evaluate the entire AST at the end of the parse. In-line evaluation is only possible for very simple (i.e. "calculator-like") projects.

Instead of an AST, you could construct code for a stack- or three-address- virtual machine. That's generally more efficient, particularly if you intend to execute the code frequently, but the AST is a lot simpler to construct, and executing it is a single depth-first scan.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language design there are at least 5 different points at which a token in the language could be bound to a value. They are:

1. Pre-processor (like C #define)
2. Lexer: recognise tokens
3. Parser: recognise token structure, output AST
4. Semantic analysis: analyse AST, assign types and conversions etc
5. Code generation: output executable code or execute code directly.

If you have a token that can occur multiple times and you want to assign it a different random value each time, then phase 4 is the place to do it. If you generate an AST, walk the tree and assign the values. If you go straight to code generation (or an interpreter) do it then.